# iOS 7: How can I disable ringer for all phone numbers but one?

Tags: iphone, ios, alert

I have a work cell phone that only rings when a server crashes. How would you disable the ringtone and text messages for every phone number except for one on iOS 7?

Comment: Considering your rep, you do know that this is off topic here right ?

Comment: I've moved it to ask different

Answer (score 1):

Try Do Not Disturb settings.   Only allow calls from Favorites and set the number you want to allow as Favorite.   Have not checked how that works with text, but will probably be handled.

Comment: Text is handled, and this is the best idea I can think of. There is a side effect that all other alerts from any application will be silenced. If that's ok (the phone is really just used for work, not also for Facebook or other apps) this is a good solution.